# Using limit and offset in subquery in Zend framework 2

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, subquery

I have two tables: users and usermeta. The table usermetahas 4 columns: id, user_id, meta_key and meta_value. A user can have many meta data.
I want to get the groups of the first 10 users. So I create a SQL query in Zend framework 2:

```
$coreSelect = $sql->select()
                        ->from('users')
                        ->limit(10)
                        ->offset(0);
$select = $sql->select()
->from(array('u'   => $coreSelect))
->join('usermeta', 
                        'u.user_id = usermeta.user_id',
                        array(
                            'meta_key'      => 'meta_key',
                            'meta_value'    => 'meta_value',
                        ),
                        Select::JOIN_LEFT
);
```

When execute this query, it show up a SQL syntax error. The SQL query string manipulated by Zend framework is like this:

```
    SELECT u.*
    FROM (
    SELECT * FROM users LIMIT '10' OFFSET '0') AS u
    ...
```

It means that Zend framework has added quotes into offset and limit value and it makes the syntax error.
Can anyone please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: How exactly do you execute your query?

Comment: hi @tu-nong, did you solve this problem? I have also having similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:
http://www.maltblue.com/tutorial/zend-db-sql-creating-joins-and-unions-with-ease
Something that interests you, towards the end, but read all of it is useful.